# R, mapply , ggplot : EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, mapply

I am trying plot the subsets of a table using ggplot and gridExtra.
But I have bumbed in the following error  EXPR must be a length 1 vector.

I could come up with any side step. Any help would be useful.

Here is a little example of what I'm trying to perform:

```
# the table
dt1 <- data.table(parkName=rep(c("Zone A","Zone B", "Zone C" ,
"Zone D"),5), boundary=rep(0:1,10),v=1:20, w=rnorm(20))[]

# criteria for subsetting the table
dt2 <- data.table(zone1 = c("Zone A","Zone B"), zone2 =c("Zone B","Zone C"))

# function for subsetting the table and plotting
p <- function(sd1,sd2){
dlist <- dt1[parkName==sd1 | parkName==sd2]    

b <- dt1[parkName %in% dlist]
a <- ggplot(
       b,
       aes(v,w)) + geom_line()
return(a)
}

mplot <- mapply(p,dt2[,zone1],dt2[,zone2])
cairo_pdf("myplot1.pdf")
do.call(marrangeGrob, c(mplot, list(nrow=2, ncol=2)))
dev.off()

# results
Error in switch(ct, ggplot = ggplotGrob(grobs[[ii.table]]), trellis =
 latticeGrob(grobs[[ii.table]]),  : EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

Comment: Didn't run your code but `dt1[parkName==sd1 & parkName==sd2]` looks a bit suspicious because you require `parkName` to be sd1 _and_ sd2 - maybe you mean _or_ instead? You could then use `dt1[parkName %in% c(sd1, sd2)]`.

Comment: my mistake thanks. I meant `dt1[parkName==sd1 | parkName==sd2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
mplot <- mapply(p,dt2[,zone1],dt2[,zone2])
```

to

```
mplot <- mapply(p,dt2[,zone1],dt2[,zone2], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

or

```
mplot <- Map(p,dt2[,zone1],dt2[,zone2])
```

`mapply()` will attempt to coerce it's result to a matrix if the dimensions of the returned objects match up, however, in this case you will always want a list. You can either set the `SIMPLIFY=` parameter to false, or use `Map()` which always returns a list.